# R loop to subset data by unique composite key

Tags: r, loops, subset

I'm trying to make a loop that will select data using as a key a few fields (field1, field2, field3)

```
   field1 field2    field3    field4 field5 field6 field7 field8
1    text  text1 segment1 31-Jan-13   2.70   0.21   1.44   1.29
2    text  text1 segment1 01-May-13   0.70   2.90   0.76   0.38
56   text  text3 segment2 01-May-14  -1.50  -1.97  -1.79  -3.51
```

When I do that by one column it works:

```
for (j in 1:length(unique(InputData[,3]))) {

  InputDataSubset <- InputData[InputData[,3] == unique(InputData[,3])[j],]
print(unique(InputData[,3])[j])  
print(InputDataSubset)  
}
```

If I try to do that by few columns:

```
for (j in 1:length(unique(InputData[,1:3]))) {

  InputDataSubset <- InputData[InputData[,1:3] == unique(InputData[,1:3])[j,],]
  print(unique(InputData[,3])[j])  
  print(InputDataSubset)  
}
```

I got error message:

```
Error in Ops.data.frame(InputData[, 1:3], unique(InputData[, 1:3])[j,  : 
  ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

How can such a problem be solved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `split(DF, DF[, c("field1", "field2")])`.

Comment: Might use `dplyr::group_by` as well.

Comment: Or: `by(DF, DF[, c("field1", "field2")], FUN=function(df) df)`

Comment: Thanks for all. Thank you @parfait  thas exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for **Parfait**

Working result looks like this:

```
InputDataSubset<-by(InputData, InputData[, colnames(InputData)[1:3]], FUN=function(df) df)


for (j in 1:length(InputDataSubset)) {
    print(InputDataSubset[j])
}
```

Comment: Glad to help as `by` is an underused but useful slice/dice method and the proposed `split` is equivalent. In `by`, replace `colnames(InputData)[1:3]` with `c(1:3)`. And for your `for` loop use: `lapply(InputDataSubset, print)`.